# Load JS for ajax page ( get script method ? )

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is the issue:
I have a page `index.php` and `onclick` of select element we load another page (`ajax`) from same folder into the `index.php` page.

The `ajax` request is performed using this:

```
var $cachedContent = $loadContainer.find(".foo").html();
var $preloadHTML = $('<div class="loader"><img src="images/loader.gif"></div>');  
$("#myads").change(function(){
//$("#adshowblock").load( $(this).val() );
var loadFile = $(this).val();
if (!!loadFile) {
    $loadContainer
    .html($preloadHTML)
    .load(loadFile, function() {
        $preloadHTML.remove();
    });
}
else {
 $loadContainer.html($cachedContent);             
}             
});
});
```

For example: On the `index.php` page, I click select box, and `banner.php` loads into the page via `ajax` request. All works perfect.

But on `banner.php` page we also need to load specific `css` and `js` files such as:

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/upload.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/swfobject.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/myupload.js'></script>
```

The issue is these files don't get loaded (if we inspect the `index.php` page) after `banner.php` is fetched they just aren't there. Should we in the `index` page (for the `ajax` request be adding get script like below (pinched from another StackOverflow answer))

If so can anyone help me do this? It's driving me crazy.

```
$.ajax({
cache: true,
dataType: "script",
url: "your_js_file.js",
success: yourFunction
});
```

**P.S.** The above code I have no idea how to initiate that using our load file `ajax` request script at top of page, a very helpful member on here made the code for us.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your scripts to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The `js` files should be loaded in when you use `ajax` to load the page, but they won;t work with an `onRead`y function, the page really isn't loading the same.

A solution I use for these type of things is to call a function once the load is done.

**In your** `loaded in` **file:**

```
var page = {
  init:function(){
    you JS file code
  }
}
```

**And in your** `ajax` **once it's finished:**

```
page.init();
```

Hope this helps!